# Instagram Thumbnails not showing on site

Tags: api, instagram, photos

I have a website that was pulling images from my Instagram account and now this morning they are not. I can't seem to find documentation on the Instagram account that explains what I need to do.

Also: my MAMP versions of the website are also drawing blanks.

Site URL: http://impressphotographymainsite2.melbourne-website-designer.com/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of your app on Instagram.com/developers and you'll probably see its now in "Sandbox" mode.

According to their site:

> Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until June 1, 2016. On that date, the app will automatically be moved to Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process.

Also have a read of their [blog post](http://developers.instagram.com/post/145262544121/instagram-platform-update-effective-june-1-2016) on the matter.

Comment: Thank you John,

What you have written makes sense as to why it was working then stopped. I am not sure that it is the issue though.

I see on my Instagram account the following: "You are not a Sandbox user for any client and there are no pending requests."

Comment: I've the same issue. Even a valid (with new access tokens) call to their own end point for recent tags is not displaying any data. :/

Comment: I think that I **might** have an idea. I've noticed that my Instagram is working on a Worpdress blog that I set up yesterday. Maybe you can only have one user ID? So it works on only one page per ID. Did you set up another page recently with the same ID?

Comment: No just the same page. Digging a little deeper, I notice that any user related api calls such as /user/self or /user/self/media/recent all work. Tags, media etc.. don't return any data.

Comment: Yata! is how you say success in Japan. I copied my "access token" from my Wordpress account plugin to my static page and I got the images back. It might not last but for now it's working. I will have to do some more testing to see if I "fixed" problem or just replaced it with a new solution.

Good luck John.

Comment: I take it your content is your own? If so you're safe. As for the scope "public_content" thats been shutdown. (see: https://becore.com/instagram-shuts-3rd-party-access-photo-content-via-api/). This completely trashes a Shopify App I'd recently submitted. Best of luck Caleb!

Answer (score 0):

I copied my "access token" from my Wordpress account plugin to my static page and I got the images back. It might not last but for now it's working. I will have to do some more testing to see if I "fixed" the problem or just replaced it with a new solution.

```
$("#instagram").jqinstapics({
  "user_id": "*********",
  "access_token": "***********",
  "count": 8
});
```